# How to pass nmap outout to a Python script

Tags: linux, bash, python

I have a list of server, and I want to nmap then pass to a Python parser ([this](https://github.com/maaaaz/nmaptocsv))

So normally I do this:

```
nmap -sV -p- hostname -oN - | python nmaptocsv.py  > hostname.txt
```

Now I want to create a bash script to do this for all lines on a txt file.

So I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
list="$1"
while read -r line ;do
 echo " processing $line "
 nmap -sV -p- $line -oN - | python nmaptocsv.py  > $line
done < "$list"
```

but this gives me an error on line 5.

Comment: error:   testscript.sh: line 5: $line: ambiguous redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the issue is you are redirecting the output of the python script back to the same variable that the while loop is creating. More than likely you are wanting to save this off possibly in a file for later reference. So probably just want to create a variable to save the output to disk.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
list="$1"
while read -r line ;do
 output="scan_${line}.txt"
 echo " processing $line "
 nmap -sV -p- $line -oN - | python nmaptocsv.py > ${output}
done < "$list"
```